# Vim: Use Unicode box drawing symbols for borders

Tags: vim, unicode

Terminals have supported box drawing symbols since the beginning of time – but Vim always insists on using ugly ASCII approximations to draw boxes and lines. For example:

- `:vsplit` creates a ridiculous column of pipes down the middle of the screen
- Folding results in a garish mishmash of hyphens and plus signs

I like Vim, but this is just a crime against fashion. Is there any way I can convince Vim to use the less awful Unicode symbols instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For styling of the vertical splits, see [this answer of mine to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001337/vim-split-bar-styling/9001540#9001540).

For the folding part, are you talking about the foldcolumn? I'm afraid those symbols can't be modified. If you are talking about the appearance of the folded line, see `:h fold-foldtext`.